# Add a unique ID to a button in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, visual-composer

I have a Wordpress one-pager (salient theme using visual composer) with four buttons.

Every one is linked to the same contact form, which is correct.

Now I want to add a specific ID to each button in order to track which one is most effective in Google Analytics.

I track my other events using Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Can you share the link to your website? With this link, I will be able to provide detailed instruction how to build triggers for each of these buttons. If it is confidential, you can send it to me by email (you can find it in my profile)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: @VictorLeontyev https://www.restillmaldiverna.se/  Since my knowledge in WordPress is fairly limited there's not much I've tested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to create a trigger in GTM:
[image]

This trigger will capture clicks on all buttons which is opening contact modal popup

2) You need to create a custom variable, which will take a heading of the section, where this button is located.
[image]
Code is: `function() {
  return jQuery({{Click Element}}).closest('.wpb_wrapper').find('.vc_custom_heading').text();
}`

3) Create a tag which will send data to GTM
[image]

4) Check your events in GA.

*Keep in mind that it might take a couple of hours to appear in Behaviour-> Events tab. Or you can check it immediately in Real Time -> Events tab*

Comment: Great! will this track each button as a separate event let say Event: klick, button1 and Event: klick, button2?

Comment: It will track each button with different event label. For example: `Event Category:'Click'`,`Event Action:'Contact Form'`, 
`Event Label:'Odenresor 60 Ã¥r! Jubileumserbjudande: Centara Grand Island All inclusive fr 19.000 kr / person'`

Comment: Oh! MANY THANKS!

Comment: Can you please check if it's working and accept my answer. And up-vote it if you think it's needed

Comment: It worked like a charm! So grateful for this. Voted ;)

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't vote, and you didn't accept it as answer

Comment: how do I vote then? only pressed the up arrow to the left

Comment: Because you do not have enough reputation. Then all is fine, thanks:)